# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).formSelect is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, materialize, turbolinks

I have 3 pages home, sign in and sign up and there is a select/dropdown on sign up page so when I'm going from home page to sign in page then sign in page to sign up page, it gives an error `$(...).formSelect is not a function` due to this dropdown not shown but when I refresh the same page it shows correctly

This is my code:-

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
    $('select').formSelect();
    M.updateTextFields();
  });
```

I'm loading scripts in this manner in application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require materialize
```

And using Turbolinks 5.2.0, Jquery v1.12 and Materialize v1.0.0 in ruby on rail

Comment: if you dynamically append data then may be arise problem

Comment: What is the version of Rails?

Comment: Rail version is 5.0.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution, by adding `data: { turbolinks: false }` in sign up anchor tag it will not happen. This is due to turbolinks so here I stopped the turbo link functionality.